# Perl - Unable to install Net::SSH2 on windows

Tags: windows, perl, ssh, sftp, windows-server

I'm attempting to install `Net::SSH2` using `cpan` on Windows. I'm unable to install and getting the following error:

**Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
    SALVA/Net-SSH2-0.69.tar.gz
    C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK**

Does anyone know why I'm receiving this error. Any help is greatly appreciated. The entire output is posted via screenshots below:

[image: screenshot of my output]
[image: screenshot of my output continued]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling `Net::SSH2` for Activestate Perl is not an easy task.

Fortunately, [Sisyphus](https://metacpan.org/author/SISYPHUS) has set up a repository of precompiled Perl packages (PPMs) which includes `Net::SSH2`: http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppmindex.html

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The output says to try downloading libssh2 from https://www.libssh2.org/
If you have libssh2 already, you could place it in a path where Perl can find it. If you look at the bottom of the output it gives a list of directories that it searches for libssh2. One of those directories would be a likely place to put libssh2.